# Append dict to a list in a for-in interation in python when the dict declared out of the list iteration

Tags: python

Like below, why does not the final r print `[{'k': 1}, {'k': 2}]` ?

```
l = [1, 2]
d = {}
r = []

for el in l:
    d['k'] = el
    print '> ' + str(d)
    r.append(d)

print r
```

OUTPUT:

```
> {'k': 1}
> {'k': 2}
[{'k': 2}, {'k': 2}]
```

It is printed as wished before append operation, however after the dict is appended to a list, why does it append the last element repeatedly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning a new value to the same key when you pass through the loop a second time.

```
for el in l:
    d['k'] = el
    print '> ' + str(d)
    r.append(d)

print r
```

The first time through the loop, `el` is `1`. `d['k']` is set to `1`, and then printed. Then `d` is appended to `r`.

The second time through the loop, `el` is `2`. `d['k']` -- the very same value of the very same key of the very same dictionary -- is set to `2`. Then the very same dictionary, `d`, is appended to `r`.

Now `r` is the same as if you had said

```
r = [d, d]
```

And since `d['k']` is now `2`, both references to `d` in the list `r` yield `{'k': 2}`.

If you want it to be different, you have to create a *new* dictionary every time through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there.  This requires just a minor fix:

```
l = [1, 2]
r = []

for el in l:
    d = {}
    d['k'] = el
    print '> ' + str(d)
    r.append(d)

print r
```

As food for thought, here is a bit more advanced way to do it using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> [{'k': el} for el in [1, 2]]
[{'k': 1}, {'k': 2}]
```